# permission denied in linux when creating a new user

Tags: linux, directory

I am new in linux and I was trying to do some commands in terminal. My problem is that when I do su to another user, and I want to create a directory there, it shows me that permission is denied. Please, help me to understand why this happens and what can I do to solve it.

```
user@user_VB:~$ sudo su
root@user_VB:~$ useradd user1 
root@user_VB:~$ groupadd students
root@user_VB:~$ usermod -g people user1
root@user_VB:~$ su user1 
user1@user_VB:~$ mkdir exams
```

Now it shows:

> permission denied.

But if I type this:

```
user1@user_VB:~$ sudo mkdir exams
```

It shows:

> user1 is not in suboers file.

Comment: where are you when you try to say `mkdir exams`? That is, what is the output of `pwd`?

Comment: the pwd is /home/user

Comment: that's it, then. You cannot make dirs in the home of another user. If you go to `/home/user1` you should be able to do so. The problem here is that you are saying `su user1`, so you remain in the same directory you were in with `root`. Instead, say `su - user1`, so you will go to the home of `user1`.

Comment: @fedorqui I did that and it shows: No directory, logging in with Home=/

Comment: OK then this is because the dir is not set automatically when creating the user. Use `useradd -d /home/user1 user1`. Check `man useradd` for more reference.

Comment: It keeps showing me the same thing, no directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two issues here.

The first is that the new user you created cannot create a new dir. This is because, even though you're changing users (user -> root -> user1), you're still in the home directory of `user`, which `user1` can't write to. What you need to do is either specify a user directory when you create the user, (`useradd -d /home/user1 user1`), as @fedorqui mentioned, or, if you've already created `user1`, use the `usermod` command to add a home directory to `user1`, like this:

```
usermod -d /home/user1 user1
```

If `/home/user1` does not exist, you'll need to, as `root`, do the following:

```
mkdir /home/user1
chown -R user1 /home/user1
```

What this is doing is first creating the directory, and then assigning ownership of it to your newly created user. So now, when you do `su - user1`, you'll end up in `/home/user1`. You should now be able to create directories and files.

Your second issue, `"user1 is not in suboers file."`, is a result of how sudo manages which users are allowed to use it. The rules that control this are in `/etc/sudoers`, which you *should* edit with `visudo`. If you wanted to allow `user1` to run whatever they want with sudo, you could add a line like this:

```
user1 ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Which says that user `user1` may run any command on the system as root. If you now try to run a command with sudo as `user1`, it will prompt you for `user1`'s password and then run the command.